# Getting Access login prompt from Crystal Report with a command parameter

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, ms-access-2010

I'm developing an app using VS2010, Crystal Reports 9 and an Access 2010 backend. When I write a Crystal Report that uses a command parameter (note...NOT a report parameter) and try to open the report in the VS app I'm getting a prompt requesting login credentials to the Access database. The database has not been set up with any security so login should not be necessary (I tried to include an image but I need more 'reputation points').

The weird thing is that if a create a mapped drive on the PC that is running the VS app that points to the network share where the CR report sits, I no longer get the login prompt. The trick here is that we don't want our end users to have these mapped drives. Does anyone know of a way for CR to pass login credentials (even empty or blank ones) back to an Access db to stop this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more work I figured it out, and it's embarrassingly simple! When I initially made the connection in Crystal Reports to the datasource that the command query was pointing to there was a mapped drive that pointed to the Access .mdb file, so when I selected it in CR, CR took the relative path name for the location of the Access .mdb. Because the users' PC's didn't have this mapped drive, I was getting the login prompt. The solution was to type in the absolute path name when selecting the datasource in CR.